# Удалить в тексте сочетание символов '\s' python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, строки

Пример предложения из текста: '{\s}{это} {то}, {что} {не} {для} {ребенок}.'
Использую re.sub python 3.x. Как удалить сочетание символов '\s'? Python понимает код как использование шаблона \s (любой пробельный символ) и удаляет все пробелы.

Comment: Если нужно просто удалить \s, то регулярные выражения не нужны. Простого replace достаточно.

Comment: Прочитал подборку http://www.rupython.com/string-replace-python-vs-re-sub-4231.html. Интересное предложение. Попробую...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно `\\\s`? Тогда первый `\` превратит второй в реальный символ а не начало escape-последовательности.

Comment: Также срабатывает шаблон на удаление пробелов.

Comment: Сработал вариант \\\s

Comment: @awegolev, изменил, чтобы помогло другим

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вот:

```
\\s
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/xWIZCD/2

> {**\s**}{это} {то}, {что} {не} {для} {ребенок}.
>
> {123}...{\**\s**}{\\\**\s**}

Сгенерированный код:

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"\\s"

test_str = ("{\\s}{это} {то}, {что} {не} {для} {ребенок}.\n"
    "{123}...{\\\\s}{\\\\\\\\s}")

subst = ""

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Comment: @awegolev https://repl.it/repls/ButteryThunderousLanserver

Comment: Вижу и понимаю, что правильный вариант \\s. НО мой результат: https://repl.it/@awegolev/WhichGoldTransversals#main.py В моем варианте \\\s

Comment: @awegolev пажждите, вы приводите мне не тот код, который у меня в ответе, и говорите, что он даёт не такой результат, как у меня в ответе? :)

Comment: Согласен. Ваш код работает. Заодно и теорию почитаю  за r в начале регвыражения '\\s'  и \\\. В обоих вариантах результат верный.

Comment: Как быть в такой ситуации по сути оба ответа правильные? За правильный можно выбрать только один.

Comment: @awegolev [вот](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) дока, ответ на свой вкус принимайте